# How to convert Mysql database to Postgresql?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I am looking for a script to convert a ~1GB Mysql dumped database containing dozens of tables to Postgresql under Ubuntu. I have tried a couple of [suggestions](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL)  but they were kind of outdated and/or buggy. There is also a Ruby app, but I had difficulty installing RVM stuff. So I really appreciate it if you could point me to a script (in Perl, Python, Bash or whatever) which you have tried and actually does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the database directly with a database conversion tool rather than dumping data and then trying to import it.

Take a look at [ESF Database Migration Toolkit](http://www.easyfrom.net/) for example .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is it Windows-only? Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Yes i have tried it, and it works well. It works only on Windows, but if you need something platform independent take a look at opendbcopy ...

Comment: Unfortunately I had no luck with either of these, probably because Java and Windows are alien to me. So need to look further.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that?

https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader

It is from postgresql website